# Checking for session expiration with Facebook Connect and .Net

Tags: .net, facebook

Is there a way in the Facebook Connect API for .Net to check if a session is expired or if it is still valid? Some times I can receive the `userId` but if I try to get any other info, it tells me that the session is expired, which is why I would like to check if the session is expired before trying to receive the uid (since I won't be able to use it if the session is expired).

Answer (score 0):

Checking Auth.getSession should return whether or not the users session is still valid.

If you're using the JS API, FB.ApiClient.sessionIsExpired will be true.

Comment: I am using the .Net API, and needs to do the check on the business layer.

Comment: Then Auth.getSession via the .NET api wrapper should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest just making a simple call to the graph of `/me` using that user's access token.  Facebook will respond with the token status. See developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/